# Match multiple result using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I want to match multiple results via regex in javascript , I tried below code.I want to match only numbers thats next to options.

```
/Option\("(\d+)"/g.exec(string)
```

Above result returns only 1 result, I searched in stackoverflow , they told to use match , so i tried below

```
string.match(/Option\("(\d+)"/g);
```

Above is returning multiple result but with full string , I just want all the available (\d+) parts.

Edit : input string is below

```
var o = 'new Option("26500","26,500.00" ); var o = new Option("26700","26,700.00" ); var o = new Option("26800","26,800.00" )';
```

Comment: What is the input string?

Comment: see my edit for input string

Comment: That input is not a string. Where is the JavaScript code converted to a string? Can you reproduce _"`/Option\("(\d+)"/g.exec(string)`
Above result returns only 1 result"_ at stacksnippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I checked at regex101 , its returning 3 result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead for the characters which come after the number you want to capture to get all the results using `String.match`:

```
(\d+)(?="\s*,\s*")
```

If you have a version of JavaScript that supports lookbehinds you can also use  a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=Option\(")(\d+)
```

Demo of lookbehind on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gEme7G/1)

```js
const str = 'new Option("26500", "26,500.00" ); var o = new Option("26700" ,"26,700.00" ); var o = new Option("26800","26,800.00" )';
const re = /(\d+)(?="\s*,\s*")/g;
console.log(str.match(re));
```

Comment: perfect this is working match(/(?<=Option\(")(\d+)/g);